# How to enable YouTube Content ID Matches via API?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I struggled with how to enable Content ID Matches via YouTube API, any one help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claims/insert. It has a sample that shows you how to upload a video, create a new asset, claim the video using the asset, and apply a monetization policy to the video. Note that you'll have to make sure that you [qualify for Content ID](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1311402) and follow the Content ID guidelines. See [How Content ID works](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?hl=en) for more information.

Another resource you might be interested in is [AssetMatchPolicy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assetMatchPolicy), which identifies an asset's match policy that YouTube applies to user-uploaded videos that match the asset..